# ¡AYUDA! "Falied to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+"

Tags: android, android-studio

Recién instalé la versión 2.1.2, pero al abrir mi proyecto me sale éste error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando doy click en *Install Repository* no abre nada, ni hace nada.

**¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?**

Comment: no se distingue el error

Comment: Parece estupido , pero has realizado lo que te indica el error log que es instalar los repositiorios que te faltan y hacer resync?

Comment: @VictorManuel Así es, tengo instalado ya el repositorio.

Comment: A mi android studio me peta cada 2 por 3 , prueba a darle Invalidate Cache/Reset creo que esta en el menu "File". Mas alla de esto no puedo recomendarte si te sigue dando problemas intenta crear un nuevo proyecto y copiar lo que tienes. Siento no poder ayudarte mas

Comment: Lo cambié por `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es buena practica usar el signo "+", si deseas usar la versión 28 debes usar como minimo Android Studio 3.1.2 y para que sea descargada debes especificar:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

como indica actualmente la IDE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**pero como es versión "beta" lo recomendable el día de hoy (Junio 2018) es  usar:**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Tienes razón, lo cambié por: `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'` y me funcionó.

Comment: @OscarAnibal Puedes usar sin problemas v7:27.1.1 solo que las demás libraries cambiarían a esta versión. saludos!